# Merging XML rowsets with matching attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, msxsl

I have an xml rowset defined similar to the following:

```
<root>
  <dataset1>
    <rows>
      <row id="0" title="Some Title" lookupValues="1;#Something1;#2;#Something2"/>
      <row id="1" title="Some other title" lookupValues="1;#Something1;#3;#Something3"/>
    </rows>
  </dataset1>
  <dataset2>
    <rows>
      <row id="1" lookupValue="Something1" anotherValue="ThisOne"/>
      <row id="2" lookupValue="Something2" anotherValue="ThatOne"/>
      <row id="3" lookupValue="Something3" anotherValue="TheOtherOne"/>
      <row id="4" lookupValue="Not Something"/>
    </rows>
  </dataset2>
</root>
```

and I'm trying to to a transform into a format more like the following:

```
<newroot>
  <rows>
    <row uniqueid="1" id="0" title="Some Title" lookupValue="Something1" anotherValue="ThisOne"/>
    <row uniqueid="2" id="0" title="Some Title" lookupValue="Something2" anotherValue="ThatOne"/>
    <row uniqueid="3" id="1" title="Some other title" lookupValue="Something1" anotherValue="ThisOne"/>
    <row uniqueid="4" id="1" title="Some other title" lookupValue="Something3" anotherValue="TheOtherOne"/>
  </rows>
</newroot>
```

Note the duplicate rows; this is a requirement for the app. Also note the
dropping of the missed lookupValue row.

Does anyone know a truly efficient way of achieving this transform?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I should have been more clear about what I was trying to accomplish. I've added some information to better illustrate the type of merge I'm looking for.

UPDATE 2: The answer that was given may have worked, except that there was an error in the original dataset; namely, the format of the `lookupValues` attribute. The delimiters are a little bit different, since the source XML contains index numbers in addition to the actual lookup text.

Comment: Well some comma or semicolon separated data in an attribute or element value to be tokenized asks for use of XSLT/XPath 2.0 with e.g. `tokenize(@lookupValues, ';')` or some similar XSLT 1.0 extension function. So which XSLT processor do you use, can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Sorry, stuck with XSLT 1.0, MSXSL.

Comment: What would happen with a `<row id="2" title="foo" lookupValues="Something1;Something4"/>` inside the first dataset when there is no matching `<row lookupValue="Something4"/>` in the second dataset? Also do the `row`s in the second dataset only have single value `lookupValue` attribute values? Or can there be semicolon separated lists of values as well?

Comment: Basically, the second dataset is sourced from lookup data with all the possible values for `lookupValues` as single values; no gaps are expected.

Comment: Can you explain in what way `dataset2` is required to create the necessary output? All I see is splitting each row of `dataset1` to individual values of `lookupValues`.

Comment: Yeah, the example I originally gave wasn't exactly what I really wanted to express. I've changed the XML to better illustrate what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your modified (again!) input. In the future, please be more considerate and think out your question *before* asking other people to spend their time on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is all pretty straightforward, with the exception of generating a unique id value for each new row. For this, I am afraid, you'll have to do two passes:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="dataset2" match="row" use="@lookupValue" />

<xsl:variable name="new-rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/dataset1/rows/row">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="values" select="@lookupValues"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <newroot>
        <rows>
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($new-rows)/row">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="uniqueid">
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </rows>
    </newroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="values"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($values, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <row id="{@id}" title="{@title}" lookupValue="{$token}" anotherValue="{key('dataset2', $token)/@anotherValue}"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($values, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="values" select="substring-after($values, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>               
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

In view of your modified input, change the `generate-rows` template to:

```
<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="values"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';#'"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(substring-after(concat($values, $delimiter), $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <row id="{@id}" title="{@title}" lookupValue="{$token}" anotherValue="{key('dataset2', $token)/@anotherValue}"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($values, $delimiter), $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="values" select="substring-after(substring-after($values, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>               
</xsl:template>
```